# Are there obvious differences between learning C on OSX and learning C on Ubuntu?

Tags: c

I'm a python programmer, and today I start my journey of C.
Now I'm using OSX, with Ubuntu in my Virtual machine, meanwhile our production servers are using CentOS.

I suppose these three systems have differences on their C libraries.
So should I pick one carefully as the learning environment according to my purpose.
Or this choice between learning environment isn't substantial, that any of these three has not that much differences and I can pick randomly?

Comment: What *is* your purpose?

Comment: Eclipse, Netbeans and Qt provide cross platform Integrated Development Environments which all work with generic ANSI C/C++ development.  Eclipse & Netbeans are Java based.  Qt is written in C/C++.  Qt also provides a C/C++ application framework which can target OS X, Linux, Android, etc.  You may find that the development environment choice to has more differences that matter to you than the OS choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write software using the [GNU C Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (gcc) on all three of those environments, without any substantial difference.

(You might like to look at the source code of some existing cross-platform packages offered by [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew).  You can grab the source code of any package using [`brew fetch ...`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md).)

However, apps written specifically for Mac OS X (or for iOS platforms), tend to be written in [Objective C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C).  This provides additional syntax unavailable in plan C or C++.  And the libraries used to create Mac OS X / iOS apps will not be available in other environments.

Whilst Objective C can be used on other platforms, learning the Apple libraries is not really a skill that you can transfer to non-Apple environments.

(And additionally, Apple are now moving from Objective C to the [Swift language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)).)

Comment: It should be noted that Objective-C is not what anyone would call "C". Yes, you can write a lot, if not most, of standard C using it but to call it the same thing would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

C is a standard not based on which operating system you use. OSX is certified Unix while Linux is only Unix-like (and getting less so) but C on Windows should be based on the same standard. So there are differences based on which standard C you are using and not which operating system.

You might get more informed answers on the Programming Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Today, few programs are written in C. This is mostly low-level things like Linux kernel or glibc. However, C is subset of C++, objective C, C# and Java is very close by syntax. So it worth learning C.

There is significant difference between usage of C on Windows and Linux, but as both MacOS and Linux are UNIX-like systems so it doesn't matter would you learn it on MacOS or Linux. For C learning purposes, this systems are equal.

Comment: With concessions for the precise meaning of "popularity" versus "few programs written", if one goes to any of the programming language statistics sites, e.g. http://langpop.com/ one can clearly see that C is currently far from "few programs" written in it.  It appears as a par or slightly in advance of C++